# Why is this code not printing the ASCII value of the given char?

Tags: c++, char, ascii

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int x;
char ch=x;
cin>>ch;
cout<<x;
}
```

When I give input as 'A' , it shows '32766'.
For input 'B', it shows the same '32766'.

Why is this code not printing the ASCII value of the given char ?

Comment: Because you never set any value to `x`, it's uninitialized and never written to in this code.

Comment: x is never initialized, or assigned any value. You assign the (indeterminate) value of x to ch, read something into ch, but never change x.

Comment: BTW, the `operator=` assigns or copies values; it doesn't mean reference.  Thus the operation of input to `ch` is **independent** of the variable `x`.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are quite new to programming. It would work if you'd output something related to the input.  Unfortunately, in your code,  x is completely unrelated to the input (and unitialized):

First improvement will just print the character:

```
char ch;
cin>>ch;
cout<<ch;
```

Second improvement will display the character as an `int`:

```
char ch;
cin>>ch;
cout<<(int)ch;
```

Or, third alternative, probably what you tried but in the wrong order:

```
char ch;
cin>>ch;
int x = ch;    // there's already a value in ch now
cout<<x;
```